# Change index in a linked list in c

Tags: c, list, indexing, linked-list, position

Can anyone help me with finding an algorithm to change a position of a node in a linked list according to the input?

Example:

I have the linked list: 1->2->3->4->END and the user chose the second node and the index 4.

The algorithm will give us the result:
1->3->4->2->END.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) find the node  2) cut it out 3) find the place to insert 4) insert it 5) profit!

Comment: > and the user chose the second node and the index 4.   Then the result should be 1->4->2->3  no? Or do you number the nodes 0-based, or right to left?

Comment: @ddbug left to right... where index 1 is the first node (the head)

Comment: Aha, so the 2nd node (2) is moved after the current element with index 4. So you find the element number 4 first, then find element number 2, then move. Optimize for case when the element to be moved sits before the final position or after it (to avoid traversing the list twice)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move node to a new index in a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640833/move-node-to-a-new-index-in-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to move nodes in a linked list because they are done for that...

To change a node's position, just change it's next pointer to the next node address, and the previous node's next pointer to the node you want to move and that's done.